# NSMutableOrderedSet causes app crash

Tags: objective-c, ios, delegates

I have a NSMutableOrderedSet which looks like this:

```
self.tableViewData = [[NSMutableOrderedSet alloc ]initWithObjects:
                                                            @"Red", 
                                                            @"Blue", 
                                                            @"Yellow", nil];
```

I'm using delegate to pass data to AppDelegate:

```
-(IBAction)add 
{
    AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[UIApplication sharedApplication].delegate;
    [delegate setData:self.tableViewData];
}
```

Here is AppDelegate.h:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableOrderedSet *data;
```

and AppDelegate.m:

```
@synthesize data = _data;
```

The problem is that the app crashes on this line:

```
[delegate setData:self.tableViewData];
```

with no error message in lldb. What is wrong here?

Comment: Have you tried to set a break point on that line and follow the code through to see what is happening?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are typecasting `[UIApplication sharedApplication]` to `(AppDelegate *)`.

Try

```
AppDelegate *delegate = (AppDelegate *)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
```